# How to hide debug Adobe Player popup window in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

When I run a Flex application in the debug flash player I get an exception pop up as soon as something unexpected happened.  I would like to catch any exception that can happen anywhere in the Flex code and if it happens don't allow Adobe Debug Flash Player open his pop up window with this exception or error.
I tried:

```
[PostConstruct]
public function init():void
{
   FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.systemManager.stage.loaderInfo.
   uncaughtErrorEvents.
   addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR,uncaughtErrorHandler);
}

private function uncaughtErrorHandler(event:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

but it don't work, general runtime error dialog will still pop up. I tried to prevent this, call event.preventDefault() inside my global error handler, but it don't work to me too. I'm using Flex 4.

Comment: But why?  This is the whole point of a debug player.   It will be fine in a regular flash player.

Comment: I want that will be fine in a debug flash player.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line to your `mm.cfg` file: `SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1` the exception dialogs will not appear any longer. The exception will still be in your flash logs.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fc9.html

Comment: Surely this only affects the Flash IDE not the SWF that end-user will interact with...? I think Asker is concerned about end-user experience.

Comment: I've used this in the past while testing a flex app to hide the debug messages. I don't think you would expect an end user to be using debug version of flash player so this wouldn't be an issue in that case.

Comment: I want this window does not appear if user use debug flash player for don't read runtime error stack trace in which he can see what libraries I use in my programm.

Comment: This setting is for debug flash only.